# Get Redmine user details by user email id

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins, redmine-api, python-redmine

Is there any `redmine` REST API available for company admin to get the details of user by giving users email id.

details like redmine KEY etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is, you can do what you want in 2 API requests:

1) http://your-redmine-url/users.json?name=user@email.com

Using this request you will get basic details for user with email user@email.com

2) http://your-redmine-url/users/193.json?include=memberships,groups

Using this request you will get additional details for user with ID 193 (which we got from previous request) like user's API key, status etc.

Also note the following:

- you need to use account with admin privileges to get these additional details
- user's API key is only available through API starting from Redmine 2.3.0
- user's status is only available through API starting from Redmine 2.4.0

All this info is from Redmine docs, which you can find [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Users).

Comment: Take into account that Redmine API use the name parameter to do a broad search:
if you have 2 users: smtih@example.com, and jsmith@example.com, looking for:
http://your-redmine-url/users.json?name=smith@example.com
will return both users!
You will have to loop through all the results of this call and check that the email you are looking for matches the email of one of the returned items.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this [Redmine Shared API](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_shared_api)

This is a plugin share some endpoints of API.

New endpoints for NON-admin users

```
[GET] /shared/custom_fields.xml | .json
[GET] /shared/users.xml | .json
[GET] /shared/settings.xml | .json
```

New endpoints for NON authorized (public) users:

```
[GET] /public/settings.xml | .json
```